# Detecting Page Load or Reload Cancel Event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, browser

During page load/reload if the Cancel button is hit the page content is partially loaded. Instead of displaying partial content is there a better way to handle this?

Say showing a message like "Page load interrupted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can handle the scenario of a canceled page load or reload by displaying a message to the user instead of partially loading the content. this is an example below, I added comments to show what does what.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page Load Interrupted Example</title>
  <style>
    .message {
      display: none;
      font-size: 18px;
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Page Load Interrupted Example</h1>

  <!-- Message element to display when page load is interrupted -->
  <div id="load-interrupted-message" class="message">
    Page load interrupted.
  </div>

  <script>
    // Wait for the DOM to be fully loaded
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      // Attach an event listener to the beforeunload event
      window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
        // Display the message if the Cancel button is hit
        document.getElementById("load-interrupted-message").style.display = "block";
        // Customize the message or take any additional actions if needed
        event.returnValue = "Page load interrupted.";
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```